# Sending email from form in spring

Tags: java, html, email, spring-mvc

Just a quick question. I was wondering if it was possible to gather the data from a form and email it directly to an email address while moving onto the next page to show the user their input?

I am currently trying to achieve this on Spring MVC but all of them show me how to send email from 2 different classes without getting data from the form. I am pretty new to Spring and Java.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but this question invites deletion since there are too many possible answers to it which won't help. Look into Java Mail for sending mail and then basic OO tutorials for how to use objects.

Comment: @AlBlue i realised that it might get deleted. I found [this](http://crunchify.com/spring-mvc-4-1-x-simple-way-to-send-an-email-using-org-springframework-mail-javamail-javamailsenderimpl/) article but it doesnt have a form . I am a little clueless as to how i would proceed.

Comment: actually this is pretty easy with  spring follow this link you can configure it with in hours http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mail.html .